# ¿Cómo llamo a esta función de python despues de definirla?

Tags: python

```
def datos(Nombre_completo, Edad, Fecha_hoy):
    """" (DOC STRING) Esta función va a separar el nombre de los apellidos de una persona, calcular su fecha de nacimiento y va a devolver todos estos datos en una lista """
   
    #split()  me permite separar palabras por espacios, como tenemos 2 apellidos habra que juntarlos de nuevo con un join.
    
    Nombre_completo = input("Dime tu nombre completo ")
    palabras =Nombre_completo.split()
    nombre = palabras[0]
    apellidos =" ".join(palabras[1:])
    
    
    #calcular el año de nacimiento, año de nacimiento = año_actual-edad
    #para trabajar con fechas utilizamos el módulo datetime.
    #la edad es un string, hay que pasarlo a int.
    
    import datetime
    Fecha_hoy = datetime.date.today()
    Edad = int(input("¿Cuántos años tienes? "))
    anno_nacimiento = Fecha_hoy.year - Edad
    

    return [nombre,apellidos,anno_nacimiento]

#Llamamos a la función

datos()
```

Comment: La llamada que estás haciendo no funcionará porque tu función `datos` espera 3 argumentos y en tu llamada le estás pasando 0. Pero como `datos` pide nombre y edad en su cuerpo no sería necesario que los pasaras como argumento.

Comment: En la rutina no utilizas los parámetros que pides, entonces, ¿por qué pides parámetros de entrada?

Comment: No uses los parámetros como forma de definir variables locales.

Answer (score 0):

La llamada que estás haciendo no funcionará porque tal y como has definido `datos`, necesita recibir obligatoriamente 3 argumentos.
Si escribes `datos(None, None, None)`, la llamada debería funcionar.

Los datos, nombre, edad y fecha los vas a pedir al usuario dentro del cuerpo de `datos`.
Por lo tanto no tiene mucho sentido que los reciba como argumentos.
Reciba lo que reciba, los va a sobrescribir.
Quizás quieras definir la signatura de tu función:

```
def datos(Nombre_completo = None, Edad = None, Fecha_hoy = None):
```

De esta forma puedes llamar a `datos` sin argumentos: los tres argumentos son opcionales.
Dentro de la función escribiremos algo como:

```
if Nombre_completo is None:
    Nombre_completo = input("Dime tu nombre completo ")
```

Lo cual significa básicamente: si en la llamada no he recibido ningún `Nombre_completo`, lo pido al usuario.

Para obtener los valores de retorno de la función:

```py
nombre, apellidos, anno = datos()
```